# Symbol ";" at the end of `define statement

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

With some simulators(for ex. VCS) the following code is passing and with some of them it brings to compilation error( for ex. Xcelium):
For example:
`define MAX_SIZE 8;

Who knows what is the reason that some simulators passing with ";" symbol at the end?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2):

The reason has to do with whether to tool is interpreting the code as Verilog or SystemVerilog. Verilog does not have the concept of a null statement, while SystemVerilog does:

```
module top;
 ;
endmodule
```

When you put a `;` at the end of a macro *and* put one at the end of the statement that uses the macro, you wind up with a null statement.

```
`defne MAX_SIZE 8;
A = `MAX_SIZE;
```

This gets intrpreted as

```
A = 8; ;
```

So it depends on whether that null statement makes sense in the context where it appears.

```
begin 
; // allowed here
case (expr)
  1: A = 8;
  2: A = 16; ; // null statement not allowed here
endcase
B = 8; ; // allowed here
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Verilog text macros are used for text substitutions. In your case `;` is a part of the macro definition. It will be placed in the text as is, for example:

```
`define MAX_SIZE 8;
...
assign abc = `MAX_SIZE
```

The last statement does not contain explicit semicolon. It is supplied by the macro when its text gets substituted there and will look like `assign abc = 8;`

**answering the comment**

It is not a good practice to use the `;` in macro definition. Verilog is very strict about semicolons ad there are other issues as well. For example, if one puts a semicolon after a such macro, as in the comment, compilation will fail because of the double `;;`

```
`assign abc = `MAX_SIZE;
```

The other example of failing compilation is declaration:

```
   reg[`MAX_SIZE-1:0] ctrl;
```

Now, the semicolon from the MAX_SIZE would stay in the way.

The best way to avoid issues in verilog with macros: do not use semicolon in macro definition, in particular when you define constants:

```
`define MAX_SIZE 8
```

However, even a better way to define constants is to use parameters. `parameter MAX_SIZE = 8;`

Comment: In my example: After the mentioned \`define line comes the following line: parameter MAX_SIZE = \`MAX_SIZE;   As you mentioned I understood that either the symbol should be removed from the first line or from the second line of code.  Because result may become abc = 8;; which will cause an issue.

Comment: I added more explanation to the answer.

Comment: I think the answer to why this works in some simulators but not others is that some simulators allow `;;`, treating the second semicolon as an empty statement.

Comment: `;;` is not a legal verilog syntax according to the standard. Most of compilers will spit an error here. Some will allow it.

Comment: `;;` is legal in certain places in SystemVerilog. See my answer.